# Converting index.html into a vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm building a webpage using Vue.js, and I'm relatively new to Javascript. I'm using Vue because I find the way it uses component .vue files makes it easier to program in Javascript.

However, looking at GitHub to help with libraries, code, etc. makes it hard, since they are usually written as one .html page.

I found a library that I'd like to use, but I'm not sure how I would create a Vue component out of it. This is because it isn't really returning anything. I'm not sure how to `export default{}` the stuff so that I'm able to use it in my App.vue.

Furthermore, the HTML and the script are kinda integrated so I was wondering would this change how I implement it?

Here is the index.html:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var map = new FlightsMap("schedules_map", {
        width: 960,
        height: 440,
        stations: "stations.json",
        flights: "flights.json"       
    });

    $("#reset").click(function() { map.reset(); });
    $("#zoom_in").click(function() { map.zoomIn(); });
    $("#zoom_out").click(function() { map.zoomOut(); });
    $("#show_schedules").click(function() { map.showSchedules(); });
});
```

```css
#station_name {
    display: inline-block; 
    float: right; 
}

a {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/santiagohecar/flights-map/master/dist/flights-map.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="schedules_map"></div>

<div style="width:800px;">
    <a id="reset" href="javascript:void(0)">Reset</a>
    <a id="zoom_in" href="javascript:void(0)">Zoom in</a>
    <a id="zoom_out" href="javascript:void(0)">Zoom out</a>
    <a id="show_schedules" href="javascript:void(0)">all</a>
    <div id="station_name" ></div>
</div>
```

From [here](https://bl.ocks.org/santiagohecar/2f8be5c36ac9a08168b10b5a10a916e4)

Comment: If it doesn't return anything, then what does it do?

Comment: @MarsNebulaSoup if you check the index.html, it looks like its defining a var map and then I'm not sure what the $(reset) does. I linked the index.html in the question, it creates that map shown in the live demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

Map.vue - this is a Vue component

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <div id="schedules_map"></div>

    <div style="width:800px;">
      <a @click="map.reset()" href="#">Reset</a>
      <a @click="map.zoomIn()" href="#">Zoom in</a>
      <a @click="map.zoomOut()" href="#">Zoom out</a>
      <a @click="map.showSchedules()" href="#">All</a>
      <div id="station_name"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
 

 
<script>
import FlightsMap from "../../node_modules/flights-map/src/flights-map";

export default {
  name: "Map",
  props: ["flights", "stations"],
  data() {
    return {
      map: {}
    };
  },
  watch: {
    flights() {
      this.createMap();
    },
    stations() {
      this.createMap();
    }
  },
  methods: {
    createMap() {
      this.map = new FlightsMap("schedules_map", {
        width: 960,
        height: 440,
        stations: this.stations,
        flights: this.flights
      });
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.createMap();
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped>
#station_name {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}
a {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 1rem;
}
</style>
```

**Installation**

You'll need to install `flights-map` with npm, or reference it from some local source. `flights-map` isn't a npm package, so you will have to install it directly from GitHub:

```
npm install https://github.com/hrcarsan/flights-map.git
```

Depending on where you locate your component, you will need to change the path to `flights-map` accordingly. When I was testing it, I had this file structure:

```
node_modules/
 ┗ flights-map/
    ┣ src/
    ┗ ┗ flights-map.js
src/
 ┗ components/
    ┗ Map.vue
 ┣ main.js
 ┗ App.vue
```

So you need to go two levels up from `Map.vue` to get above `node_modules` and `src`, then down to `flights_map/src/flights-map.js` Also note that there is a `dist/` directory in `flights-map/`, with a different `flights-map.js`, but that one doesn't work properly. So make sure that your path goes to the `src` directory, not `dist`

**Using Map.vue**

App.vue

```
<template>
  <Map
    stations="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hrcarsan/flights-map/master/example/stations.json"
    flights="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hrcarsan/flights-map/master/example/flights.json"
  ></Map>
</template>

<script>
import Map from "@/components/Map.vue";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    Map
  }
};
</script>
```

Whenever you want use the Map component, just call it like so (note that you need to import it on each seperate view you use it on) :

```
<Map
    stations="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hrcarsan/flights-map/master/example/stations.json"
    flights="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hrcarsan/flights-map/master/example/flights.json"
></Map>
```

`stations` is the url of `stations.json`.

`flights` is the url of `flights.json`

**Sidenote**:

The watchers in Map.vue aren't required, they are there just to make the map reactive. You can remove them and the `createMap()` method too. Just put the contents of `createMap()` in `mounted()`

Comment: Thanks a lot, This worked perfectly, I cant tell you how much this helped. However, I have a question which I'd like to ask. Its quite specific so I dont really want to post it as a question. Could I email you perhaps?

Comment: My email is in my profile, if you want to contact me